# In PowerShell can you Write-Host the invocation and arguments for an external command?

Tags: powershell

In my PowerShell (v5), I am calling lots of external commands like msbuild, dotnet, etc.  (I'm making PowerShell build scripts).

I want to log the command that is running.  How do I do that?

Here is one example, but I don't want to duplicate the command as a Write-Host statement.

```
Write-Host "dotnet restore --source $MyNuGet --source $NuGet"
dotnet restore --source $MyNuGet --source $NuGet
```

I want the output in my log to be:

```
dotnet restore --source https://blah --source https://blah2
```

Is there some way to do this?  Can I create a command execution wrapper of some kind?  Or can I build the command as a string, and then I can pass it to Write-Host and also pass it to Run-Command or something like that?  Maybe I will answer my own question.  I wonder if I can pass the string to "&".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more brute-force way of doing this, which would be quite chatty, I admit, would be to do:

```
Start-Transcript <path to output file>
... run your commands ...
Stop-Transcript
```

and you'll have a very verbose log to comb through (especially if you're running interactively and have custom prompt code). Note, this is enabled by registry key, but in Windows 10 it appears to be enabled by default.

Or, more in line with your original example:

```
function Invoke-Wrapper {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][scriptblock]$ScriptBlock
    )
    Write-Host "$ScriptBlock"
    
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
    $rc = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $lastExitCode } 

    Write-Host "{ $ScriptBlock } returned: $rc"
    if ($rc -ne 0){
        exit $rc
    }
}

Invoke-Wrapper { my command(s) }
```

Comment: Hi Guac!  Much appreciated.  One problem is that Invoke-Command eats all the command output.  I tried doing `$stdout = Invoke-Command`, but all the newlines are missing.  I gave up.

Comment: You're not doing something that double-wraps the script block, are you, as in `$sb = { do something that creates output}; Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $sb }`?

Comment: No I'm not. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

As I finished typing the question I thought of a wrapper idea and found `Invoke-Expression`.  So I was able to create a cool wrapper like this:

```
function Invoke-Wrapper {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Expression
    )
    Write-Host "$Expression"
    Invoke-Expression $Expression
    Write-Host $Expression.Substring(0, 12)"... exit code: $lastExitCode"
    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0){
        exit $LastExitCode
    }
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
Invoke-Wrapper "dotnet restore --source $CustomNuGet --source $NuGet"

Invoke-Wrapper "dotnet publish $StartUpProjectFilePath --configuration Release --version-suffix $AppVersion"

Invoke-Wrapper "Compress-Archive -Force $StartUpProjectDriectory\bin\Release\netcoreapp*\publish\*  $pwd\Artifact.$StartUpProjectName.$AppVersion.$buildResultKey.zip"
```

The only problem I can think of is that if the commands have quotes they might get messed up, but my third example works.  Are there other answers or easier ideas?

Comment: Careful... you can get yourself downvoted for using `Invoke-Expression` in a Powershell answer... sorta like using `eval` in Javascript...

Comment: Haha.  That's fine as long as I learn.  I can always delete this answer if it is bad.  Do you have another idea?

Comment: Try my last example. It swaps your string for a script block, which may get around your quoting issues, and avoids `Invoke-Expression`

Comment: This answer seems to show stdout properly, but I gave up on the wrapper idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different idea that accomplishes *mostly* what I want.  It's less glamorous, but I needed a compromise since the other ideas were starting to go down the rabbit hole.  If I was better at PowerShell, I might be able to make them work.

Instead I just call Log-* functions before and after the command.  It does not log the full command, but I can figure that out by looking at the script.

```
function Log-Begin {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$CommandName
    )
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "Calling: $CommandName"
}

function Log-End {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$CommandName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$exitCode
    )
    Write-Host "Finished: $CommandName"
    Write-Host "        : returned exit code: $exitCode."
    if ($exitCode -ne 0){
        Write-Host "Got a bad exitCode: $exitCode.  Exiting $PSCommandPath."
        exit $exitCode
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Log-Begin "dotnet restore"
dotnet restore --source $CustomNuGet --source $NuGet
Log-End "dotnet restore" $LastExitCode
```

Now at least all of my commands have common logging and return code processing.